# error: no matching function for call to 'DollarAmount::DollarAmount(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'

Tags: c++

I'm receiving this error from g++:
`error: no matching function for call to 'DollarAmount::DollarAmount(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'`

I also get notes from gcc saying that less arguments were provided than expected and there is no known conversion for argument 1 to const DollarAmount&.

I've tried looking at the main function but all classes seem to be passed two parameters.

DollarAmount.h

```
// Ex. 5.30: DollarAmount.h
// DollarAmount class gets two parameter constructor
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

class DollarAmount {
public:
    // initialize amount from an int64_t value
    explicit DollarAmount(int64_t dollars, int64_t cents) : amount{dollars * 100 + cents} { }

    // add right's amount to this object's amount
    void add(DollarAmount right) {
        // can access private data of other objects of the same class
        amount += right.amount;
    }

    // subtract right's amount from this object's amount
    void subtract(DollarAmount right) {
        // can access private data of other objects of the same class
        amount -= right.amount;
    }

    // uses integer arithmetic to calculate interest amount,
    // then calls add with the interest amount
    void addInterest(int rate, int divisor) {
        // create DollarAmount representing the interest
        DollarAmount interest {
            (amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor
        };

        add(interest); // add interest to this object's amount
    }

    // return a string representation of a DollarAmount object
    std::string toString() const {
        std::string dollars{std::to_string(amount / 100)};
        std::string cents{std::to_string(std::abs(amount % 100))};
        return dollars + "." + (cents.size() == 1 ? "0" : "") + cents;
    }
private:
    int64_t amount{0}; // dollar amount in pennies
};
```

Interest.cpp

```
// Ex. 5.30: Interest.cpp
// Compound-interest calculations with class DollarAmount and integers.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "DollarAmount.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    DollarAmount d1{123, 45}; // $123.45
    DollarAmount d2{15, 76}; // $15.76

    cout << "After adding d2 (" << d2.toString() << ") into d1 ("
        << d1.toString() << "), d1 = ";
    d1.add(d2); // modifies object d1
    cout << d1.toString() << "\n";

    cout << "After subtracting d2 (" << d2.toString() << ") into d1 ("
        << d1.toString() << "), d1 = ";
    d1.subtract(d2); // modifies object d1
    cout << d1.toString() << "\n";

    cout << "After subtracting d1 ( " << d2.toString() << ") from d2 ("
        << d2.toString() << "), d2 = ";
    d2.subtract(d1); // modifies object d2
    cout << d2.toString() << "\n\n";

    cout << "Enter integer interest rate and divisor. For example:\n"
        << "for     2%, enter:    2 100\n"
        << "for   2.3%, enter:   23 1000\n"
        << "for  2.37%, enter:  237 10000\n"
        << "for 2.375%, enter: 2375 100000\n";
    int rate; // whole-number interest rate
    int divisor; // divisor for rate
    cin >> rate >> divisor;

    DollarAmount balance{1000, 0}; // initial principal amount in pennies
    cout << "\nInitial balance: " << balance.toString() << endl;

    // display headers
    cout << "\nYear" << setw(20) << "Amount on deposit" << endl;

    // calculate amount on deposit for each of ten years
    for (unsigned int year{1}; year <= 10; year++) {
        // increase balance by rate % (i.e., rate / divisor)
        balance.addInterest(rate, divisor);

        // display the year and the amount
        cout << setw(4) << year << setw(20) << balance.toString() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error comes from `addInterest` where you're trying to call a constructor with a single element. Don't do that.

Comment: Next time, please copy-paste the full error message, which indicates where the error happens. It makes it a lot easier to find the problem!

Comment: Definitely will screenshot it in the future (also fixed the addInterest member function, thanks)

Comment: There is no reason `addInterest()` needs to call `add()` with a `DollarAmount` when it has access to just update `amount` directly, eg: `void addInterest(int rate, int divisor) { int64_t interest = (amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor; amount += interest; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the `addInterest()` method, where you create a `DollarAmount` using an initializer list with only one value, while the only defined constructor takes two values.

```
void addInterest(int rate, int divisor) {

    //Right Here Is What The Error Is About
    DollarAmount interest {
        (amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor
    };
    //
    add(interest);
}
```

Comment: The problem is not with the initializer list itself, but that the list contains only 1 value in it, but the sole constructor defined takes 2 parameters That is why `DollarAmount d1{123, 45};` and `DollarAmount d2{15, 76};` work, but `DollarAmount interest { (amount * rate + divisor / 2) / divisor };` fails.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just changed it so no one will get confused by my wrong reasoning, thanks!